# isset or !isset for php or different usuage

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Hello I am having a problem with my php code. This error is probably small in size. What I want to do is add select information if not all info is present. Like using isset or !isset. So if I have movie and cast information i can add it to my database. However using isset returns with error of no directorid. just want to continue.

```
try {    
    $input = new Input();

    $movieid = $input -> Integer('movieid', ' movieid error');
    $castid = $input -> Integer('castid', ' castid error');
    $directorid = $input -> Integer('directorid', ' directorid');

    if(!isset($directorid)) {
        addMoviecasts ($movieid, $castid);
    } else { 
        addMoviedirector ($movieid, $directorid);
    }

} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Movie Info Exception' . $e -> getMessage());
}
```

Comment: `$directorid` is going to be whatever value you return from this `$input->Integer` method. That means directorid will ALWAYS be set to something, even if it's just a null or false value.

Comment: What is `Input` what is the exact error message you got

Comment: It seems that you have to use `empty()`, not `isset`

Comment: `isset` has so many exceptions, that your code will almost always be confusing, because . Nowadays, I try to avoid isset as much as possible, and rather use more specific functions like `is_null`, `array_key_exists` or a strict `=== false` comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `$directorid` right here:

```
$directorid = $input -> Integer('directorid', ' directorid');
```

So it will be always set, even when `null` or empty string will be in it. To check if variable has value, use [empty()](http://www.php.net/empty) function.

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, after moving my inputs into the if statement, my code now works.